# Noobs wireless detection

Tags: sd-card, wireless, noobs

Im reinstalling my raspberry and once i inicialize noobs and search for networks it does not detect my home network but it detects my neighbours.

Once it install the raspbian OS, the OS already detects my network.

I tried resetting the router and fresh formatting and reinstaling the sd card.

Do you guys have any clues?

Comment: The experienced users on this site don’t use NOOBS. It takes longer to install and wastes space.

Comment: Hi @NmRfG, Well, for any hardware/software config/setup, if your neighbour networks are detected, but not your poor own home network, I am pretty sure it is your home router's fault.  In other words, there is nothing to do with your Rpi (never mind regular/full or noobs version), Arduino, or Windows.  Your home router is likely SwitchedOff/WronglyConfigured/Dead/Broken/Signal weaker than your far away strong neighbours, who are LOL.

Comment: Don't use NOOBS. Just flash a [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Comment: My pi is next to the router, and even after i factory reseted the router it did the same. It installs raspbian perfectly but i wanted to install the elecOS.